# Get Category Name, from which product was ordered

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, sales-order, sql

Currently my product belong to many Categories, I want to get Category Name, from which product was ordered.

Comment: where you want the category name on **sales->order** grid of admin or somewhere  else please specify.

Comment: Yes, I have created my custom grid from order items, I want it there

Comment: have you ever made use of renderer ?

Comment: Did you find any best way>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abdul Ghaffar,**magento does not save category details** at sales model.So it not possible *to  get Category Name, from which product was ordered*.

Magento save order only product id,sku at sales module.

If you want to then you need do customization,first you *need to add a field to at sales_quote_item  & sales_flat_order_item*.

**During cart**,you need to add **category id**  to **sales_quote_item** table.

***During  order place, convert that field value to sales_flat_order_table***

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item['product_id']);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();

foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
     if (in_array($category_id, $elements)) {
          echo $_cat->getName();
     }
}
```