# magento 2 get category id in ordered product

Tags: magento2, sales-order

Magento 2 how to get Ordered product category id

> My problem is i have same product with multiple category so i want
>   know which category product i place order based on order id

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
->loadByIncrementId('000000004');
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
  echo "<pre>";
  echo $itemQty = $item->getProductId();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId('000000002');

$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());

$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

}
```

Comment: No I already got this answer my problem is i have same product with multiple category so i want know which category product i added based on order id

Comment: This is actual in magento 2:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/get-category-name-from-which-product-was-ordered

You must save this info manually. Try to use observer, for example before order create.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer to get category ids.

```
$product_id=20;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
print_r($cats);exit;
```

Thanks

Comment: No I already got this answer my problem is i have same product with multiple category so i want know which category product i added based on order id